# Ue4 2D Sprite Exposure Issues

Tags: 2d, textures, sprite, unreal-engine4

I have been working on a 2D game and have come across a strange problem. All my sprites seem to have some sort of filter making them very bright as if they have some sort of high exposure setting. Heres a picture:

[image: An image of my project, notice the scene is set to 'Unlit']

If anyone could help I would much appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the sRGB flag of your textures. Also try setting them to UI in case you do not want them to use mipmaps (I guess because your sprites seams quite pixel-arty).

Comment: Thank you very much this appears to be the problem ;)